# Not round a column

Tags: python, pandas, date-difference

I'm creating a new column in phyton with the day differences between two columns to get the days differences in years
I'm using this code:

```
difference = df1['col1'] - df1['col2']
df1['Supp_Age'] =  difference.dt.days / 365.25
```

And I'm getting the expected output,
but automatically it's rounding the number for example if the result it's 8.65 it rounds it to 9

Do you know a way to unround that number?
So if the result it's 8.65 I want to keep the 8 not rounding

Answer (score 1):

Instead days you can convert timedelta to seconds and divide by `86400` for days:

```
df1['Supp_Age'] =  difference.dt.total_seconds() / 86400 / 365.25
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['2016-06-01 10:02:10', 
                            '2017-06-01 15:15:20', '2016-04-01 09:02:31'], 
                   'col1': ['2018-01-01 12:16:12', 
                            '2019-01-01 20:10:36', '2017-04-01 20:00:00']})

df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_datetime)

difference = df1['col1'] - df1['col2']
df1['Supp_Age'] =  difference.dt.days 
df1['Supp_Age1'] =  difference.dt.total_seconds() / 86400 
print (df1)
                 col2                col1  Supp_Age   Supp_Age1
0 2016-06-01 10:02:10 2018-01-01 12:16:12       579  579.093079
1 2017-06-01 15:15:20 2019-01-01 20:10:36       579  579.205046
2 2016-04-01 09:02:31 2017-04-01 20:00:00       365  365.456586
```